# drop1 returning error in R

Tags: r, anova

I've been running ANOVA tests in R and have been trying to convert the results to Type III results. However, using the normal `drop1` function gives an error message. My code is below as well as the error message. Any help or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

`mixed1 <- aov(Score~(Label*X)+Error(ID/Label)+X, cesmixed1   )
drop1(mixed1,~.,test="F")`

*Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula*

Comment: We also need your data or a way to simulate some data that illustrates the problem. Otherwise you're giving us more work to do.

Comment: I don't think `drop1` works when `aov` has an `Error` term.  But for balanced designs (which is what `aov` was made for) Type I and Type III SS will give the same results (see, e.g., [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-August/056503.html).)   For unbalanced designs, one option is the "marginal" tests in `lme` in package nlme, see [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/type3.htm) or just do a quick web search for  more info.